# Does ActiveRecord wrap manual queries into a transaction already?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a query that begins and ends a transaction like this:

```
transaction = "BEGIN; UPDATE articles set x = 1 where id = 1; UPDATE articles set x = 2 where id = 2; END;"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(transaction)
```

My question: Do I even need the BEGIN and END? Does ActiveRecord already wrap my query into a transaction?

Answer (score 9):

[ActiveRecord provides the transaction method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html), available on both AR classes and instances, that will wrap queries within a given block. It even supports nested transactions.

You could rewrite your code as:

```
sql = <<-SQL
UPDATE articles set x = 1 where id = 1; 
UPDATE articles set x = 2 where id = 2;
SQL

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```